# Proper way to initialize data from react-query

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-query

edit: passing data as parameter into onSuccess worked for me

```
const [location, setLocation] = useState(null)
const [address, setAddress] = useState('')
const [desc, setDesc] = useState('')

const { data, isLoading, isError } = useQuery(["order"], async () => getOrders(id), {
    onSuccess: (data) => {
        setAddress([data[0].location.address.streetName, " ", data[0].location.address.buildingNumber, data[0].apartmentNumber ? "/" : '', data[0].apartmentNumber])
        setDesc(data[0].description)
        setLocation(data[0].location)
    }
})
```

I can't initialize state with data from react-query. States are updating only after refocusing the window. What is the proper way to fetch data from queries and put it into states?

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom"
import { useQuery } from '@tanstack/react-query'
import { getOrders } from '../../api/ordersApi'
import { useState } from 'react'
import { getLocations } from '../../api/locationsApi'

const Order = () => {
    const { id } = useParams()
    
    const [address, setAddress] = useState('')
    const [desc, setDesc] = useState('')
    const [location, setLocation] = useState(undefined)

    const { data, isLoading, isError } = useQuery(["order"], async () => getOrders(id), {
        onSuccess: () => {
            if (data) {
                setDesc(data[0].description)
                setAddress([data[0].location.address.streetName, " ", data[0].location.address.buildingNumber, data[0].apartmentNumber ? "/" : '', data[0].apartmentNumber])
            }

        }
    })

    const { data: locationData, isLoading: isLocationLoading, isError: isLocationError } = useQuery(["locations"], getLocations, {
        onSuccess: () => {
            if (locationData) {
                setLocation(data[0].location)
            }
        }
    })

    if (isLoading || isLocationLoading) return (
        <div>Loading</div>
    )
    if (isError || isLocationError) return (
        <div>Error</div>
    )

    return (

            data[0] && locationData && (
                <div>
                    <h2>Zlecenie nr {data && data[0].ticket}</h2>
                    <h1>{address}</h1>
                    <textarea
                        type="text"
                        value={desc}
                        onChange={(e) => setDesc(e.target.value)}
                        placeholder="Enter description"
                    />
                    <select
                id="locations"
                name="locations"
                value={JSON.stringify(location)}
                onChange={(e) => setLocation(JSON.parse(e.target.value))}
            >
                {locationData?.map((locationElement) => <option key={locationElement._id} value={JSON.stringify(locationElement)}>{locationElement.abbrev}</option>)}
            </select>
                    <h1>{location?.abbrev}</h1>
                    <pre>{data && JSON.stringify(data[0], null, "\t")}</pre>

                </div>)
        
    )
}

export default Order
```

I know I am doing something wrong - data is queried but states are set to values from useState(). Please check my code and help me get into what is wrong here.

Comment: Here `data[0]` should be `locationData` I guess: `if (locationData) {
                setLocation(data[0].location)
            }`

Comment: Does this even work. `data`s inside `return must have been `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks for help, I had to pass `data` into `onSuccess: (data) =>` callback

Answer (score 0):

Consider the [query keys](https://tanstack.com/query/latest/docs/react/guides/query-keys) (first parameter that you passing) of `useQuery` like `useEffect`'s dependency array. Whatever you passed there, if it changes query will refetch too, just like how it's done on `useEffect` hook.

In your example, it seems like you have a `desc` state, and when it changes you want to query re-fetched and set to `address` and `location` states.

In your code, there is a logical mistake in that you have a text area that sets `desc` state and you are trying to make a request with it and storing the response in the same state.

True approach is create a state to store your desired query (like location) use it as a key in `useQuery` and store the data to another state. Even better, you can use the [useReducer](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useReducer) hook to store your data in a form format to have more readable and stable approach

Comment: Passing data as a parameter in `onSuccess: (data) => {...}` worked for me. Thanks for tips, I will keep them in mind.